# What stack to use if I want to develop

Tags: web-apps, react, postgresql, django, vue.js

Let's say I want to develop a Real Estate fullstack web application.
With a

- Reactive map component
- Authentication
- Social Network authentication
- Image storage
- Data storage
- GIS querying capabilities
- Chat *optionnal*
- High rate data querying (I don't know the limits of relational DBs)
- Cache *optionnal*

I having been working with vanilla react in the past and Django. I know well Python and JS.

So I hesitate between React / Vue and the framework on top of these technologies, Nust, Next and Gatsby (I never develop a web app from scratch so these frameworks might help?). I know React and a little VueJs and what I saw is that I can have a great productivity using VueJs.

For the DB I don't really know what I should use and I hesitate between MongoDB (I have been working with Firestore and it's amazing but quite complicated when having multiple collections) and PostgreSQL. I will have to work with GIS data and PostgreSQL has the ability to query these fields types. I don't know if it is the same for MongoDB.

For the backend I will go for Django because I want the simplest way to develop APIs. I don't know if should take a look to Node.js related products (express ...)

What I'm looking for are tools that will allow me to go **fast**, to have a very clear and organised code structure with simple and proven tools that work well together.

Let me hear your thoughts !

Comment: Ok, but actually any web framework would qualify.

Comment: I'm not sure whether we answer stack questions on this site. If you ask me about my C# stack, I need to describe 50+ tools